# dynamic method dispatch in java. How to call the methode of parent class?

Tags: java

In the class Album I have an ArrayList of visuals where I add a new Visual. Visual class is a parent class and it has also a child class Movie. Each of this classes has a method play(). When I call method play() in the method addVisual() in the class Album , it calls the method of child class(overriding). But I want to call the  play() method of parent class. How can I do it?

```
    // class Album
    public boolean addVisual(Visual newPhoto)
    {
    for(Visual h: visuals)
    {
        if(h.play().equals(newPhoto.play()))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    visuals.add(newPhoto);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: create instance of parent class then ? or use `super` ?

Comment: In general you use [`super`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) to invoke method of a parent class.